# Counting the number of words and write the result back to an excel file

Tags: python

I have an excel file with a column "id" and a bunch of text files of which file names match with the "id" listed in the excel file.  I want to go through all the files, count the number of words, and write the result back to the excel file under the column "word_count". The following code seems to correctly count the words in the corresponding files, but fail to write the result back to the excel file.  I can't figure out why...any advice?

```
file names: 
1
2
3
...
```

```
'test.xlsx'
id     word_count
```

```
Output ("id" corresponds to the file name): 

id     word_count
1      3298
2      589
3      3487
4      1649
...    ...
```

```
info = 'test.xlsx'
dir = 'text'

import os
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_word_counts = []
number_of_words = 0

for file in Path(dir).glob("**/*.txt"):
    with open(file, "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        text = f.read()
        word = text.split()
        word_count = len(word)
        number_of_words += word_count
        file_word_counts.append((file.stem, word_count))
        
df = pd.read_excel(info)
for file_stem, word_count in file_word_counts:
    match = df['id'] == file_stem
    if match.any():
        df.loc[match, 'word_count'] = word_count
        
df.to_excel(info, index=False)
print("Word count done.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the [`stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) of a file is a string (*i.e* `<class 'str'>`).

You need to cast it to `int` to match the dtype of the column `id` (*which is* `int64`) :

```
        file_word_counts.append((int(file.stem), word_count)) # <-- updated
```

Or later when making the boolean mask :

```
for file_stem, word_count in file_word_counts:
    match = df['id'] == int(file_stem) # <-- updated
    if match.any():
        df.loc[match, 'word_count'] = word_count
```

Note that you can also make a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) between the `id`s with the corresponding *w-counts*.

```
info, dir_ = 'test.xlsx', 'text'

file_word_counts = {}
number_of_words = 0

for file in Path(dir_).glob("**/*.txt"):
    with open(file, "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        word_count = len(f.read().split())
        file_word_counts[int(file.stem)] = word_count
        number_of_words += word_count

df = pd.read_excel(info)
df["word_count"] = df["id"].map(file_word_counts)
# if there is no match, NaN will be assigned to missing id
        
df.to_excel(info, index=False) # this will overwrite the original file
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It all worked out.